# Autoscaling Greenplum on GKE does not behave in the correct manner

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling, greenplum

Good evening, everyone.

I have installed Greenplum on a GKE cluster which is running fine (following the guide [here](https://greenplum-kubernetes.docs.pivotal.io/2-3/prepare-gke.html))

The problem now is that the autoscaling is not correctly adding pods: it creates the new pods and after 5 seconds they are in a terminated state.
I have already created the GKE without the "alpha configuration" as it was specified in another StackOverflow's question.

No errors are thrown, but i see these in the logs:

```
E0301 16:49:01.684087    2685 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod 62b01d0a-0890-416b-b288-b3ec943d70ba ("segment-a-1_default(62b01d0a-0890-416b-b288-b3ec943d70ba)"), skipping: unmounted volumes=[greenplum-system-pod-token-78b9b ssh-key-volume config-volume my-greenplum-pgdata cgroups podinfo], unattached volumes=[greenplum-system-pod-token-78b9b ssh-key-volume config-volume my-greenplum-pgdata cgroups podinfo]: timed out waiting for the condition 

E0301 16:49:01.731718    2774 kubelet.go:1686] Unable to attach or mount volumes for pod "segment-a-2_default(c82d8954-1b17-4be6-a262-13ddc7c991b3)": unmounted volumes=[config-volume my-greenplum-pgdata cgroups podinfo greenplum-system-pod-token-78b9b ssh-key-volume], unattached volumes=[config-volume my-greenplum-pgdata cgroups podinfo greenplum-system-pod-token-78b9b ssh-key-volume]: timed out waiting for the condition; skipping pod
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Hello, Can you try the following and share with us the results?

1.- https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/3643

2.- Try by increasing the readiness and liveness probes https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

Comment: Thanks @Jujosiga, let me try

Comment: For the moment, i had to scale vertically. I'll add info i come back to this